# Android observe data not being called

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android development and am trying to get my head around the architecture but have spent the past 2 days trying to figure out `LiveData`

I am using an SDK which allows me to scan some sensors, I display the sensors on the device and  then toggle a switch to connect the sensor. Once the sensor is connected I have created a button which runs a funcion called `startMeasuring()` everytime some data is measured a callback is hit and this is where my struggle begins.

In my `MainActivity` I have the following code which is ran once I toggle the switch to connect to the sensor.

```
public void onConnectedSensorClick(BluetoothDevice sensor, Integer position, Boolean checked) {
    XsensDotDevice xsDevice = new XsensDotDevice(this, sensor, new XsDevice(this));

    if (checked) {
        xsDevice.connect();
        mMainActivityViewModel.addConnectedSensor(xsDevice);
    }
}
```

The `XsensDotDevice()` expects 3 parameters the context, scanned sensor and the callback class.

In my callback calss the following callback function is overridden

```
@Override
public void onXsensDotDataChanged(String s, XsensDotData xsensDotData) {
    
}
```

This function is the one which gets triggered when I start measuring and the sensor sends the device a measurement.

I am have created a `ViewModel` and `Repository` which is what I want to use to store this data so I can access it back in my `MainActivity` using an `Observer`

I got the `ViewModel` and `Repository` working for my scanned devices but I'm not sure how to get this working for the measurement data because I can't access the `ViewModel` in my callback class `XsDevice()` to pass the data to the `Repository`

What I want to do is somehow pass the `XsensDotData` (measurement data) to the `SensorDataRepository` and then create an `Observer` in my `MainActivity` like so.

```
mMainActivityViewModel.getSensorData().observe(this, new Observer<XsensDotData>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(XsensDotData xsensDotData) {
        for(int i = 0; i< xsensDotData.getFreeAcc().length; i++){
            Log.d("Sensor Data Acceleration " + i, String.valueOf(xsensDotData.getFreeAcc()[i]));
        }
    }
});
```

I have already created a `Repository` and `ViewModel` which i will show below

**Repository**

```
public class SensorDataRepository {
    private static SensorDataRepository instance;
    private XsensDotData dataSet = new XsensDotData();

    public static SensorDataRepository getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SensorDataRepository();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<XsensDotData> getSensorData() {
        MutableLiveData<XsensDotData> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        data.setValue(dataSet);
        return data;
    }

    public void addSensorData(XsensDotData data) {
        dataSet = data;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>> mScannedSensors;
    private ScannedSensorRepository mScannedSensorRepo;

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<XsensDotDevice>> mConnectedSensors;
    private ConnectedSensorRepository mConnectedSensorRepo;

    private MutableLiveData<XsensDotData> mSensorData;
    private SensorDataRepository mSensorDataRepo;

    public void init() {
        if (mScannedSensors != null) {
            return;
        }
        mScannedSensorRepo = ScannedSensorRepository.getInstance();
        mScannedSensors = mScannedSensorRepo.getScannedSensors();

        if (mConnectedSensorRepo != null) {
            return;
        }
        mConnectedSensorRepo = ConnectedSensorRepository.getInstance();
        mConnectedSensors = mConnectedSensorRepo.getConnectedSensors();

        if (mSensorDataRepo != null) {
            return;
        }
        mSensorDataRepo = SensorDataRepository.getInstance();
        mSensorData = mSensorDataRepo.getSensorData();
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>> getScannedSensors() {
        return mScannedSensors;
    }

    public void addScannedSensor(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mScannedSensorRepo.addScannedSensors(device);
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<XsensDotDevice>> getConnectedSensors() {
        return mConnectedSensors;
    }

    public void addConnectedSensor(XsensDotDevice device) {
        mConnectedSensorRepo.addConnectedSensors(device);
    }

    public LiveData<XsensDotData> getSensorData() {
        return mSensorData;
    }

    public void addSensorData(XsensDotData data) {
        mSensorDataRepo.addSensorData(data);
    }
}
```

I included the code for the scanned and connect devices in the `ViewModel` in case it come in handy and helps explain whats going on.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how I use LiveData. In my view model I will have a value as so :

```
var isInternetAvailable = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = true }
```

in my activity I will have the code:

```
viewmodel.isInternetAvailable.observe(this, Observer {
// execute your logic here
 var theValue = viewmodel.isInternetAvailable.value!!

}
```

Then in my viewModel when the internet has changed I will use

```
viewmodel.isInternetAvailable.postValue(true)
```

So for your code - as far as I can see,  you're observing the function but not posting to it in order to trigger your observer function

You can use

```
 MutableLiveData<XsensDotData> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

and then

```
data.postValue(dataSet)
```

That should hopefully trigger your observer

Comment: Thanks for the example, Im a bit confused by your answer because am I right in thinking I can't access the `MainActivityViewModel` from my `XsDevice()` class because it isnt an activity? This is where I am struggle if everything was done in the activity I can easily post new values to the `ViewModel` allowing me to observe it but how do I do this from the `XsDevice` class?

Comment: You could make your  MutableLiveData<XsensDotData> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
a global value and put it outside of the viewModel class, that way any class or activity can post to it and observe it

Comment: additionally, you could pass an instance of your view model to the SensorDataRepository class like so SensorDataRepository(private var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel) then when you instantiate :
  private SensorDataRepository mSensorDataRepo = SensorDataRepository(this)